# Regular expression looking for multiples values

Tags: regex, apache

I'm doing a redirection for a few links in my site, and I'm using a regular expression like this:

```
/thigs/([^(wood | \?n= | stone)].*)
```

I want to discard all the concurrences that contains the word 'wood' or 'stone' or '?n='. It works but only with '?n=' it ignores 'wood' and 'stone'

Comment: im using that in a .httaccess file so no php

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a character class for this. The character class `[wood]` is exactly the same as `[dow]`.

```
/thigs/(?!(wood|\?n=|stone).*)
```

**Related**

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: thanks!!!!!!, it works, but now i have another doubt


if it only contains /things/ its not ignored

so if i do, i think that im saying that has to be something after /things/ so it works to ignore when the string is only /things/

/thigs/.(?!(wood|\?n=|stone).*).*

but not ignore when i say
/things/wood/

what im missing here?


in ressume i want to

/things/ ignore
/things/wood/ ignore
/things/stone/ ignore
/things/?n= ignore
/things/?n=whateverword ignore

/things/whateverword/ NOT ignore